# Why have about 200 of my Pokémon disappeared in 18 hours?

Tags: pokemon-go

Has anyone dealt with a bunch of Pokémon disappearing  and what did you do about it? I lost about 200 since yesterday afternoon!

Comment: Maybe someone hacked into your account and turned them all into candies?

Answer (score 1):

Not a bug or anything that's been encountered before.  Although it's possible that this was an error with the game, the likely options are that:

- Someone used your phone and deleted them
- You've accidentally logged into a different account